# extreme situations in a fuzzy phenomenon

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, british-english, collocation

I wanna point to extreme cases of a fuzzy phenomenon but I don't know how to call them:

```
- two ends of the spectrum
- two head of the spectrum
- ...
```

I'm wondering if someone tell me, how a native speaker call it.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+heads+of+the+spectrum%2Ctwo+ends+of+the+spectrum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20ends%20of%20the%20spectrum%3B%2Cc0) can be relied upon.

Comment: First, settle on a metaphor. Is this phenomenon alive? If so, it may have a head; otherwise, not. Is this phenomenon continuous (like wind) or discrete (like lightning)? What kind of fuzziness is involved -- is this just handwaving or are there numbers? How many dimensions of variance are there? If there's more than two (which seems likely if it's "fuzzy") then the spectrum is not one-dimensional and has more than two ends.  A common metaphor is the prototype in the center and varying instances in orbit, like an atom, but with millions of electrons and thousands of valence shells

Comment: If if you choose use 'head' then the other end would be 'tail'. Head and tail are used in many contexts but I don't think I have heard it related to spectra.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about, but please do not write "wanna". It is not an English word. (I would advise you not to say it either.) The English is "want to". Also "what to call something", not "how to call something".

Answer (score 1):

"Spectrum" is often used as a metaphor to describe something that has many different possible states, each close to many others. For example, I read a book called "The Forager Spectrum" discussing the wide variety of cultures that are generically called hunter-gatherers.

When using "spectrum" in a figurative sense, talking about the ends or extremes is quite common. I fully agree with the comment that talking about the heads of a spectrum would sound very odd because it would imply that a spectrum is a kind of two-headed animal.

Answer (score 1):

"Ends" of the spectrum is completely natural and idiomatic for native English speakers, while "heads" would likely not be used.  The idea of a "spectrum" is based on the spectrum of light, and denotes something that changes gradually from one extreme to another.

Typically, I hear "*opposite* ends" of the spectrum, which highlights the opposition.

> "My brother and I are at two opposite ends of the spectrum, when it comes to personal hygiene."

Answer (score 0):

Not very common but you could use 'head' and 'tail'. This would suggest that the head part contains more (of whatever you are measuring or counting), and the tail less.

See this example
[image: graph]